# Convert .AIB (Audio Media indexer ) file into readable format (String)

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I want to parse a .AIB file which I have got in the form of output from Azure media indexer job So that I can read the data in the file and can take out the required information.

Answer (score 0):

The AIB file format is a binary blob designed for use with the SQL Server Add-in.  Have you read through the blog post here? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-aib-files-with-azure-media-indexer-and-sql-server/

If you have any more questions after reading that blog post, or you already have, I can help you further.

Would you mind sharing your scenario that requires the AIB file?  Almost all of our customers have found that the plain-text outputs are sufficient for their use cases.

Adarsh

Comment: Thanks @asolanki for helping:                                                                                               1.) I want to parse .aib file so that I can get the time frame for particulate word or phrase in it. Like I can Parse TTML file and get the required detail because it is in XML format.                                                                      2.) My purpose is to get all the required detail (Start,End Time in which word or phrase lie ) regarding the word or phrase in the output aib file for the indexing Job for particulate video with out using TTML file.

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have any code samples for parsing the AIB format.  This format was made solely for use with our SQL Server Add-in.

Have you tried using the .info file?  This can be generated by generating the keyword file.